# Bank in another state asking family member questions about me upon opening a line of credit

Tags: united-states, banking, credit

Today my aunt let me know that she tried to open a line of credit with a credit union she uses in the state she lives in (a different state than I live in). She told me my name came up and they started asking her about ten total questions, such as where I lived, etc. She said it sounded like they were looking for me. Even though I did live in her state over ten years ago, I have never even heard of the bank she's using, and aside from student loan debt, I have no other debt I'm aware of.

Do they have the right to do this? Additionally, could a private student loan company (I have a loan from a terrible company that I cosigned on) have something to do with this (even though they're a separate company) as a scare tactic?

Also checked my credit report; nothing fishy on there.

Very confused since her opening a line of credit has nothing to do with me, and can't call them yet since tomorrow's a holiday. But I've never even heard of a bank doing this.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add country tag.

Comment: Sure, country tag is added now.

Comment: Could it be that the teller was trying to check if she's opening a line of credit to give you money? I believe the law requires the banks to avoid giving money to people when there's elderly abuse suspected.

Comment: .. or protect against the fake-ransom scam. I think @littleadv has the right reason. More generally: they can ask most non-predjucicial questions; she doesn't have to answer but they don't have to issue the loan.

Comment: Is it possible that when doing a credit check that your data is similar to your aunt's data, and when they said here are 3 addresses have you ever lived at any of them, and one of them was your old address.

Comment: Yeah, she made it sound like there were "several personal questions" regarding previous addresses I had, current addresses, and that those were sent to her specifically over email (also strange). None of my data would be similar to hers except for last name. I don't know why they'd even be concerned with my info when I've never used that bank and it's apparently for her 2nd or 3rd line of credit...why would my name be even pulled up? And if they're concerned it's money for me, why me and not some other relative? Only makes sense to me if she was trying to open a line of credit in my name.

Comment: How much do you trust your aunt? My feeling is that she was putting you down as a co-signer on the line of credit.  I had an "America's Most Wanted" level fraudster with my name who I would get asked about often, but only to show I wasn't him.  This smells very fishy, keep an eye on your credit report for new accounts.

Comment: @Ukko: If the aunt were trying something shady here, why would she mention it to the OP at all?

Comment: Yeah, I don't really trust what's going on because it doesn't make sense - I called the bank and they weren't actually looking for me. They said sometimes they can ask non-personal questions about a relative upon someone opening a line of credit, but nothing like addresses. So I thought that she might be putting me as a co-signer down or involving me in some way, though as of now there's nothing on my credit report - and like @NateEldredge said she probably wouldn't have mentioned me at all.

Comment: @NateEldredge I read this wrong "regarding previous addresses I had, current addresses, and that those were sent to her specifically over email" thinking the OP had sent the address to her aunt.  But another thing that comes to mind is was it in a question like "here are three addresses have you lived at one of them?"  Sometimes credit reporting agencies will ask those sort of questions with plausible incorrect answers to trip up people googling the info.  Your aunt knows she never lived at your address, but a scammer might look at the similar names and take a chance.

Comment: @Ukko - Agreed that sort of question would make more sense, though she said there were about ten questions total, many of which were specifically about me. She said that she's gotten questioned before like this at a bank about my brother and that it's "normal when they're looking for somebody" (she said this even after I told her I talked to the bank and they had nothing on my name or SS). So I'm thinking she's doing something fishy.......no idea what that would be, though.